# Interior of sets

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

The following question is from an intermediate calculus book I am going through:

Find two sets in $\mathbb R^2$ that have the same interior, but whose complements have different interiors.

This seems like the kind of question that should be fairly straightforward, but I just can't think of an answer. I have tried, for instance, taking the first set to be $\mathbb R^2$ minus an open disc and comparing with $\mathbb R^2$ minus a closed disc. However the complements have the same interior. I have also tried the same with removing single points, squares etc, but nothing seems to work. If anyone can shed any light on this I'd be very grateful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tell us what have you attempted anyways :)

Comment: If you add an isolated point to the set then it won't change the interior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $A=\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ and $B=\emptyset$. Clearly, $\text{Int}(A)=\text{Int}(B)=\emptyset$ but $\text{Int}(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus A)=\emptyset$ and $\text{Int}(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus B)=\text{Int}(\mathbb{R}^2)=\mathbb{R}^2$

Answer (score 0):

{0} and {0,1}........................